# Solved : Dual boot, Grub is not running when PC starts and ubuntu is not in the boot settingd

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, startup

It's been a year since I have my computer in Windows 10 with an Ubuntu dual boot which worked perfectly until then. However, I suddenly no longer had the choice of operating system at startup and when I tried to see my ubuntu in the boot list with F2 at startup I only found Windows.

https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/46/3/1605115050-img-20201111-180425.jpg

My computer is an Acer aspire 5 (A515-51-56VN).

Thanks you for your help,
Vincent

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I cannot do the Boot-Repair in Ubuntu because I can only acces my windows 10 system (maybe I didn't understand what you told me, sorry if it is the case)

Comment: You run Boot-Repair from the Ubuntu live installer in live mode. See link on how to then add it to the Ubuntu installer. Windows may have done Windows update and UEFI udpate. IF UEFI update, settings may have been redone to defaults. Check your UEFI settings like Secure Boot, AHCI, fast boot and any others you changed. I have a list that I keep.

Comment: Thanks you for the explanations, I finally managed to access my ubuntu partition with a USB key with the Ubunto ISO on it and I launched the boot repair, here is the result : http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/gB6zjMTcgt/            Should I do the boot repair ?

Comment: "Unknown Device" is classic Acer where you have not set "trust" on the Ubuntu boot entry. Make sure you have latest UEFI from Acer. You have to have Secure boot on, create password (never lose it or reset when done or you have a brick), or you have a brick. And then set trust. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003 Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot

Comment: I manually created the Grub boot as said in the second link and it worked perfectly thanks you !

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this might be an issue with Ubuntu being corrupted (I could be wrong probably)

First off try going to your computer's BIOS (how you access it depends on your manufacturer, it's something like DEL, F12, or something like that when it shows the computer's logo).

Check on boot priority and if it doesn't show Ubuntu then maybe the Ubuntu OS has been coroupted.

Check if windows even stored the Ubuntu files first
https://www.howtogeek.com/261383/how-to-access-your-ubuntu-bash-files-in-windows-and-your-windows-system-drive-in-bash/

Comment: As you can see in the picture I shared on my first post, I can't find Ubuntu in my boot priority on the BIOS. I tried to check if windows stored the Ubuntu files but I can't find anything that looks like the files showed in your link. But I tried to use EasyUEFI and it finds my ubuntu partition as you can see in this screenshot : https://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2020/46/3/1605121699-capture.png

Comment: problem is with the update today..

Comment: herenis. mine http://imgur.com/a/J2j5aCp

Comment: You mean that the last Windows 10 update caused the problem ?

Comment: No, ubuntu update